# Partial specialization and static member

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
template<typename T, bool is_derived = false>
struct A
{ 
    T v_;

    static const char* getMehStatic();
    virtual const char* getMeh() const { return getMehStatic(); }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<std::vector<T>> : public A<std::vector<T>, true>
{
    static const char* getMehStatic();
};

template<typename T>
const char* A<std::vector<T>>::getMehStatic() { return "vector"; }

int main()
{
    A<std::vector<int>> a;

    std::cout << a.getMeh();
}
```

When I compile this, the linker complains that it can't find a `getMehStatic();` this is because it looks for that of the generic type. In other words, it seems to skip my attempt at providing an implementation of the partially specialized `A<std::vector<T>>` .

I'm deriving my specialized class from the generic version, using the default parameter to select the correct one, otherwise the specialized class would derive from itself.

I've tried all sorts of things - preventing the `getMehStatic()` in the generic version to be generated using `enable_if<>`, various ways of doing the specialization, none work (I have several different error messages depending on what I try, so probably not very helpful to post them all here). So, how do I partially specialize a static member function, in such a way that the specialized function overrides the function in the generic class?

Comment: You need to provide `A<std::vector<T>, true>::getMehStatic()`.

Comment: What is the purpose of inheritance: `A<std::vector<T>/*, false*/> : public A<std::vector<T>, true>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42: I tried that, then I get "error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list" (VS 2017), or "20 : <source>:20:58: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A<std::vector<T>, true>'
" (g++), both of which I don't understand.

Comment: @Jarod42 to use the functionality that the generic version provides; in my real code it has a bunch of members and functions. Yes I could refactor so that I wouldn't need to do that, then I wouldn't have this problem at all, but it works fine with full specializations and with non-static member functions, so I'm thinking there should be some way in the presented case too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how do I partially specialize a static member function, in such a way that the specialized function overrides the function in the generic class?

via CRTP, something like

```
template<typename T, typename Derived = void>
struct A
{ 
    T v_;

    static const char* getMehStatic();

    virtual const char* getMeh() const {
      if constexpr( std::is_same_v<Derived,void> )
        return getMehStatic();
      else
        return Derived::getMehStatic();
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<std::vector<T>> : public A<std::vector<T>, A<std::vector<T>> >
{
    static const char* getMehStatic();
};

template<typename T, typename Derived>
const char* A<T,Derived>::getMehStatic() { return "generic"; }

template<typename T>
const char* A<std::vector<T>>::getMehStatic() { return "vector"; }
```

Comment: Well yes, that's another way of putting it - my question is how do I get it to use the specialized version?

Comment: OK thank you - I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this, but I guess (after thinking it over) that having a CRTP parameter isn't worse than having the boolean parameter I have now.

Answer (score 2):

definition of `A<std::vector<T>, true>::getMehStatic()` is missing.
unfortunately, you cannot partial specialize it. you can provide the generic definition:

```
template<typename T, bool is_derived>
const char* A<T, is_derived>::getMehStatic() { return "generic"; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cec3a0428946cff)

but as `A<std::vector<T>>` doesn't override `getMeh()`, it is the generic method which is called.

CRTP can indeed resolve that:

```
template<typename T, typename Derived>
struct A
{ 
    T v_;

    const char* getMeh() const { return Derived::getMehStatic(); }
};

struct B : A<std::vector<int>, B>
{
    static const char* getMehStatic() { return "vector"; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb01d19372aafcfe)

Comment: OK thanks - can you also explain why the partial specialization isn't possible here, but the full is? I expected this to work: template<typename T> template<> inline const char* A<std::vector<T>, true>::getMehStatic() { return "-"; } but that seems to be illegal.